# pstricks pspicture psgrid - nothing displayed on output

Tags: pstricks

Morning,
I tried to make a simple grid and also drawing a line (handy-like). My lines are basic. I used MikTex with TexStudio. Compile is ok, a PDF is done but nothing on it, except the page numbering - in this case the "1". I'm out of clues...

Here is my code :

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{pstricks-add} %for the handy line

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{pspicture}(-1,-1)(2,1)
        \psgrid(-1,-1)(2,1)
    \end{pspicture}

    \begin{pspicture}(0,-0.5)(3,0.5)
        \pslineByHand(0,0)(3,0)
    \end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

and the msg from system when compiled :

```
Process started: latex -src -interaction=nonstopmode "untitled-1".tex
Process exited normally
```

TiA.

Comment: Are you sure to compile with the DVI->DVIPS->PS2PDF mode ?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! What if you try compiling with `xelatex`?

Comment: Your code works fine for me. Please try your coding with either `xeLaTeX` or `LaTeX -> dvips -> PS2PDF`, if still the error exists then post your `.log` file details

Comment: Why not use auto-pst-pdf?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. My bad. It was the compiling method i used. As comments told by **other users** above, I tried the DVI / PS / PDF and it works fine now. I think the process in TeXStudio is not as easy as it seems. I have not configured the app after the install, maybe it's the problem. Thank you all for your help.